# Scala underscore in typescript - implemented but impossible to type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Pretty sure its impossible, been a pet project of mine for 2years now to implement Scalas underscore in Typescript but can't quite get there this is the implementation and the effect.

The only thing i care about the type of is "Underscore" everything else just ignore.

```
const buildUnderscore = (f: any) => (path: any[]): any => new Proxy(f, handler(path));
const handler = (path: any[]) => ({
    get: function(obj: any, prop: any, value: any) {
        return buildUnderscore((a: any) => getAtPath(a, path.concat(prop)))(path.concat(prop));
    }
})
/* takes object A and key path ["a", "b", "c"] -> returns A["a"]["b"]["c"] */
const getAtPath = (obj: any, [head, ...tail]: string[]): any => {
    if(head === undefined) return obj;
    return getAtPath(obj[head], tail);
}


/* Ignore all implementation above i don't care if its typed this is the only thing i care that's typed */
const _: Underscore = buildUnderscore((a: any) => a)([]);


// ConvertKeysToFunctions<GetArgs<Array<T>["map"]>[0]> is what i need
// but there's no way to infer T
// where GetArgs gets the first argument of Array["map"]
// and ConvertKeysToFunctions converts that types keys to function types
type Underscore = <T>(a: T) => T

const data =  [
        {
            child: {
                name: "bob",
                children: ["sue", "john"]
            }
        },
        {
            child: {
                name: "catness",
                children: ["rue", "hew"]
            }
        },
    ]
console.log(data.map(_))  // converts to data.map((a) => a)
console.log(data.map(_.child.children[0]))// converts to: data.map((a) => a["child"]["children"][0])
console.log(data.map(_.child))  // converts to data.map((a) => a["child"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TypeScript is currently missing the ability to refer to a dynamic name of the property of an object which makes proxies poorly usable / typeable with TypeScript.

Probably the closest thing you can have is to just use a lambda:

```
_ => _.foo.bar
```

If any of the properties on the path are optional you would have to use dark type magic like I did in [my library for similar purpose](https://github.com/grassator/getting/blob/master/src/index.ts). Be warned though using something like that can dramatically slow down the compilation process.

Comment: Thanks but the whole purpose of the Scala underscore is to not use a lambda